# nginx limit_req does not work

Tags: nginx, webserver, url-rewriting, rate

I'm trying to implement a simple rate limiting system with nginx (v1.6.2)

**sites-available/mysite.com**:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=myzone:10m rate=2r/m;

server {
    listen                      80;
    server_name                 mysite.com;
    root                        /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com;
    error_log                   [..];
    access_log                  [..];

    include                     conf.d/php-fpm.conf;

    location = / {
        limit_req               zone=myzone burst=3 nodelay;
        index                   index.html;
    }

    location / {
        try_files               $uri =404;
    }

    location ^~ /pages {
        include                 conf.d/php-fpm.conf;
        internal;
    }

    location = /email {
        rewrite ^(.*)$          /pages/email.html;
    }

    location = /email/subscribe {
        limit_req               zone=myzone burst=2 nodelay;
        rewrite ^(.*)$          /pages/email.php?action=subscribe;
    }

    location ~ /api {
       limit_req                zone=myzone burst=5 nodelay;
       rewrite ^(.*)$           /pages/api.php;
    }
}
```

**conf.d/php-fpm.conf**:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    fastcgi_pass                unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index               index.php;
    fastcgi_param               SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_split_path_info     ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_param               PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    include                     fastcgi_params;
}
```

**nginx.conf**:
Nothing interesting, only
`include                        sites-enabled/*;`

Rate limiting `/` works fine. I get an error 503 if I do too many requests to this page.
The problem: Neither `/email/subscribe`, `/api` nor `/api/test` is rate limited, and I don't know why. It must have to do something with `rewrite`, but what's the problem?
Any ideas? I tried everything!

**Please note: I've changed filenames and URL endpoints.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that nginx process request in several [phases](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases) and *rewrite* phase goes before *preaccess* one (this is where `limit_req` is applied). So in you config requests are rewritten to `/pages/...` before they had a chance to be limited. To avoid this you either should stay in the same location block after rewrite (using `break` flag) or a little hack with `try_files`.

I prefer first option, so your config could look like this:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=myzone:10m rate=2r/m;

server {
    listen                      80;
    server_name                 mysite.com;
    root                        /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com;
    error_log                   [..];
    access_log                  [..];

    include                     conf.d/php-fpm.conf;

    location = / {
        limit_req               zone=myzone burst=3 nodelay;
        index                   index.html;
    }

    location / {
        try_files               $uri =404;
    }

    location ^~ /pages {
        include                 conf.d/php-fpm.conf;
        internal;
    }

    location = /email {
        rewrite ^(.*)$          /pages/email.html;
    }

    location = /email/subscribe {
        limit_req               zone=myzone burst=2 nodelay;
        rewrite ^(.*)$          /pages/email.php?action=subscribe break;
        fastcgi_pass            unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include                 fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /api {
       limit_req                zone=myzone burst=5 nodelay;
       rewrite ^(.*)$           /pages/api.php break;
       fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_param            SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include                  fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

If you go with second option, your config will be a little cleaner, but a bit hacky. We will use the fact that `try_files` phase runs after `limit_req` phase and that `try_files` makes internal redirect to it's last argument.

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=myzone:10m rate=2r/m;

server {
    listen                      80;
    server_name                 mysite.com;
    root                        /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com;
    error_log                   [..];
    access_log                  [..];

    include                     conf.d/php-fpm.conf;

    location = / {
        limit_req               zone=myzone burst=3 nodelay;
        index                   index.html;
    }

    location / {
        try_files               $uri =404;
    }

    location ^~ /pages {
        include                 conf.d/php-fpm.conf;
        internal;
    }

    location = /email {
        rewrite ^(.*)$          /pages/email.html;
    }

    location = /email/subscribe {
        limit_req               zone=myzone burst=2 nodelay;
        try_files SOME_NONEXISTENT_FILE /pages/email.php?action=subscribe;
    }

    location ~ /api {
       limit_req                zone=myzone burst=5 nodelay;
       try_files SOME_NONEXISTENT_FILE /pages/api.php;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, is this really the only possible way? I mean this is *really* hackish.. :(

Comment: whats SOME_NONEXISTENT_FILE?

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper any file name that not exists in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyTen. Is there a way to add a connection limit on the `/api/index.php` file. My server has the above path for all APIs and I want to add a connection limit on this file? I have tried a lot of things and spent hours figuring the right thing.  Is there any solution?

Comment: @AlexeyTen. Can you check my question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/578781/nginx-limit-req-not-working-in-location-directive-for-an-index-file ? Maybe you can have answers to my issues.